# Get the dropdown selected value in bootstrap python flask

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I have this dropdown that is made with bootstrap with a couple of options and I want to get the data of the selected value with flask.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle text-right " type="button" id="dropdownMenu3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                age
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
                {% for i in range(110) %}
                    <button class="dropdown-item text-right " type="button">{{i}}</button>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Python:**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def home():


        return render_template("home.html")
     
    return app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bartosz's answer is valid, but the below code does the same without using Javascript

html

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('test') }}">
<div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle text-right " type="button" id="dropdownMenu3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                age
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
                {% for i in range(110) %}
                    <button name = "age" value = {{i}} class="dropdown-item text-right " type="submit">{{i}}</button>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

app.py

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def test():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form.get('age'))
    return render_template("test.html")
```

you need wrap the dropdown div in Form and specify its action.

Comment: That works but I want to style it with bootstrap since I don't know CSS and I made the dropdown and everything and it is just different.

Comment: I did edit the answer. Also, please bear the difference between dropdown and other methods of input. Drop down menu is similar to the one the old code produced while the one you are creating is not a drop down.

Comment: Ok, thank you and one last thing.
I want which value I choose will be instead of "age" and It will wait to click a button and not automaticliy get it.

Comment: I am not sure If I understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to highlight the selected age and the age is retrieved only if you click the submit button ?

Comment: In this case you need to add javascript to notify you about the selected button and highlight it.

Comment: Ok I figured out how to do it with the first thing u did just added style and it looks way better

Answer (score 0):

Create a form with dropdown and button for submiting the form, then create js script that extract selected option and send it to the backend by HTTP POST method.

Comment: I don't know javascript